# Loop ID through cells in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good Day! I would like the Purchase Order ID repeated upon submission of a form in an earlier sheet. My current code however repeats this throughout the length of data range. Can I get help in modifying the code or loop/if statement below? Thank you in advance.

```
function exportPO() {
var myGooglSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var shSource = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Source");
var shDatabase = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Database");
var lastRow = shDatabase.getLastRow()

var ProductValues = shSource.getRange("B5:C14").getValues();
shDatabase.getRange(lastRow+1,2,ProductValues.length,2).setValues(ProductValues);

var PO = shSource.getRange("C1").getValues();
var lines = 0;

var ProductRow = ProductValues.length;
for(var i=0; i<ProductRow; i++)
  if (ProductValues!=''){
  lines= lines+1;
  shDatabase.getRange(lastRow+lines,1).setValues(PO);
  shDatabase.getRange(lastRow+lines,4).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm- 
  dd h:mm'); //Submitted On
```

Comment: As a guess, try to change the `if (ProductValues!=''){` to `if (ProductValues[i][0]=''){` or `if (ProductValues[i][1]!=''){` or something like this. Since the `ProductValues` is a 2D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relation to

```
var ProductValues = shSource.getRange("B5:C14").getValues();
```

The above line assigns a Array of Arrays to `ProductValues`

In relation to

```
ProductValues!=''
```

The above expression always will return `false`. You might change this to `ProductValues[i].every(value => value != '')` to compare all the values in a row to an empty string, if all are not a empty string, this will return true, otherwise false, or change the original expression to something like `ProductValues[i][0]!=''` to compare on value of each row to an empty string, the first index corresponds to the row, the second to the column.